# EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'endSourceSpan' of null

Tags: angular

looking for some help.

I recently did a code merge with another person on my project and am now receiving the error: EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'endSourceSpan' of null.

I cannot for the life of my figure out what is causing this. I've gone through every single Typescript and HTML file and everything looks valid. This is driving me crazy, as the entire app is blown up and will not load.

Any ideas what this error could be referring to? I'm seeing references to invalid HTML, but curious if anything else could cause this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid and Angular fails to parse it. If you post the source we can have a look. Probably a missing closing tag, missing closing quote, ...

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks for the quick reply. When you say source - are you talking about the actual HTML code? I have several templates that I would need to combine - just want to make sure. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. As Gunter said, it was an issue with the HTML.

I ended up removing each template and reloading the app until I figured out which one was breaking it.

I then scoured the HTML (beautified, really), and found an extra closing .

Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: in my case I had made two errors- missed a `"` and used `+` instead of `=` in the html code...i think you get this error when something is wrong with html